# Bar button item tint colors with iOS bold text settings

Tags: ios, swift, tintcolor

I've received a screenshot from my app by an older lady who seems to have activated "Bold text" in her iPhone settings.

Since I've never really looked at that before and my app does not support dynamic text (which seems to not be related) I was surprised to see that in this mode the tint colors I gave my bar button items are being ignored and they'll always show in standard iOS Nav bar button blue, this line of code does not have an effect anymore:

```
myBarButtonItem.tintColor = myColor
```

In my case the color indicates their state so that's a dealbreaker.
I know that I could detect whether the user has activated this setting (as indicated in the answer here [Possible to detect Bold Text setting in Settings > Accessibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329238/possible-to-detect-bold-text-setting-in-settings-accessibility) ) and indicate the state by using different icons...

But is there any way around this and keep my tint colors in bold text mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try with appearance

UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = yourcolor

Comment: As you would probably have noticed if you tried it, that does not help, voting it up yourself, even though it is not the right answer, doesn't either.

Comment: In my current project, I am using appearance setting only. And it is working on my simulator. I am a responsible developer and I am posting only after testing. And upvote has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Well, it is not the answer to my question. You can set the appearance of bar button items generally with that line but a) it does not work with the iPhone text set to bold in the Setting's accessibility and b) I need to set them individually as in my case, they are dependent to state.