# Detect "Bold Font" option in accessibility settings programmatically

Tags: android, accessibility

On some Android devices the user can set "Bold Font" in its accessibility settings. In Pixel 5 this setting is availale in Settings > Accessibility > Text and Display.

I like to know how is it possible to detect is this setting is set. I can't seem to find any relevant part in Android docs. A [simliar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23329238/177006) exists in StackOverflow for iOS.

[image: Bold text option in Settings > Accessibility > Text and Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for, but there is a Field in the configuration class called `fontWeightAdjustment` that might be what you are looking for.
If you do not know how to get that configuration class, you can do this in any activity:

```
Configuration config = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
int fontWeight = config.fontWeightAdjustment;
```

Note that this field is only available from API level 31 (Android 12).
If you want to know more about this field and the configuration class head to the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#fontWeightAdjustment)